# Combinatorics (Partitioning - Divide 9 choices evenly among three)

Tags: combinatorics

Nine impact wrenches are to be divided evenly among three assembly lines.

In How many ways can this be done? The answer in the book states that it is 240 but I can't figure out how they've arrived at this number.

My thinking is that assembly line 1 has ${9 \choose 3}$ ways to the allocate the first 3 wrenches, then assembly line 2 has ${6 \choose 3}$ ways to allocate the second 3 wrenches, then assembly line 3 has ${3 \choose 3}$ ways for the final 3. Multiplying these numbers gives me $1680$

Can someone either confirm that I've done this correctly or tell me what I'm doing incorrectly?

edit:

The book has a follow-up question: two of the wrenches are used, and seven are new. What is the probability that a particular line (line A) gets both used wrenches?

which I've calculated to be $(7!)/(3!\times 3!) = 140$ which out of all possibilities is $140/1680 = 0.0833$

This matches the answer they have ($1/12$), so I believe that $240$ was a mistake.

Comment: This would give me 280 =/= 240

Comment: Fixed it. That was a typo, you're correct

Comment: Yeah, 1680 seems right to me.